# Distance between very large discrete probability distributions

Tags: clustering, probability, distance

I have 192 countries where each country has some value for 1 million attributes which sum up to 1 (a discrete probability distribution). For any one country most of the values for the attributes are 0.

Now I am trying to find the distance/similarity between those countries using these attributes. I know we can use  [Jensen Shannon Divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%E2%80%93Shannon_divergence) between two discrete probability distributions to get a distance measure, but the caveat is that all the values have to be non-zero.

Given that there are zero valued attributes for the countries, is there any other suitable statistical distance measure that can help me to cluster these countries using these 1 million attributes?

Comment: Use regularization so none of the probabilities are precisely zero. You should be using regularization anyway; it reduces variance. Welcome to the site.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? Do you mean replacing 0 with very small non-zero value?

Comment: For example, while ensuring the result still adds to unity. Read about Bayesian priors and conjugates.

Comment: You can use zero values in the JSD by invoking the limit $\lim \limits_{x\to 0^{+}}x\log (x)=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, plenty.

Get the book "encyclopedia of distances".

For example, you can use Histogram Intersection distance. Since your data is already normalized, that reduces to Manhattan distance, if I am not mistaken. Yes: this can be appropriate for distributions.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using some kind of smoothing to the probability distribution, e.g., [Laplace smoothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_smoothing) (sometimes known as "add-one smoothing").  Then, you will be able to use the Jensen-Shannon distance.

Or, you can use some other distance metric, such as [earth-mover's distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mover%27s_distance) or [total variation distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures).  Which metric is most suitable might depend on details of the application domain and the desired interpretation of these distances.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Kullback–Leibler divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#Definition), aka relative entropy, which is a measure of how one probability distribution diverges from a second, expected probability distribution. It handles attributes that have 0 value.

Comment: Kullback–Leibler divergence only handles zeros through applying the limit $\lim \limits_{x\to 0^{+}}x\log (x)=0$. This limit also applies to the Jensen Shannon Divergence (the 'distance' suggested by the OP). So, in the sense of zeros, the KLD is no different to the JSD.